# GWT emulated indexOf() is incorrect compared to jdk indexOf()

Tags: java, arraylist, gwt

For some reason GWT emulated (client side) jdk method indexOf() is not working as expected.

Example:.

I have a list containing 3 NaN objects:

```
List<Double> doubleList = new ArrayList<Double>();
doubleList.add(Double.NaN);
doubleList.add(Double.NaN);
doubleList.add(Double.NaN);
```

I retrieve min value, which is Double.NaN:

```
Double minValue = Collections.min(doubleList); //minValue = Double.NaN
```

So far everything is working  as expected in client and server side.

Now I am trying to get index of minValue:

```
Integer index = doubleList.indexOf(minValue);
```

This is where the fun begins. Server side (simple unit test) jdk ArrayList class method indexof() returns `0`, as it should. While emulated ArrayList class (client side) returns `-1` which is not correct, because `-1` should be returned when value is not found in the list which is clearly not the case.

Any ideas why is this happening?

GWT indexOf():

```
  int indexOf(Object o, int index) {
    for (; index < array.length; ++index) {
      if (Objects.equals(o, array[index])) {
        return index;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }
```

GWT emulated [class ArrayList](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/master/user/super/com/google/gwt/emul/java/util/ArrayList.java)

Comment: Is there the same problem for Integer or Long lists?

Comment: @vanje Haven't tested Integer/Long, though I assume there won't be any difference. Note that this is only for NaN objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In JavaScript `NaN === NaN` is false](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) but in Java `Double.NaN.equals(Double.NaN)` is true. So the comparison in the method `indexOf()` doesn't work for NaN. The correct implementation would use the JavaScript function `isNaN()` in this case.

Comment: That makes sense, though I somehow doubt that method indexOf() was changed going from 2.7.0 to 2.8.2 version and NaN comparison works with 2.7.0 version (now to find 2.7.0 indexOf emulation)

Comment: It would be interesting to look at the compiled JavaScript code for both versions. Unfortunately, I don't have time for such things.

Comment: Can one of you file this at github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues so it can be resolved?

Comment: @ColinAlworth registered this at github.